# org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.reactive.vertx.VertxInstance]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, vert.x

I'm using Spring Boot - Webflux - Hibernate Reactive - Postgresql as my technology stack for my web app. All the endpoints retrieve endpoints are working, but the save user endpoint do not. Could anyone help me understand why the exception?

The exception produces after`Mutiny.SessionFactory factory = CustomEntityManagerFactory.getInstance().getEntityManagerFactory(idCC).unwrap(Mutiny.SessionFactory.class);` . In other endpoints, the CustomEntityManagerFactory is working well.

```
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Transactional
    public void save(User user) throws Exception {
        try {
            Mutiny.SessionFactory factory = CustomEntityManagerFactory
                    .getInstance()
                    .getEntityManagerFactory(null)
                    .unwrap(Mutiny.SessionFactory.class); // Exception is produced here

            // Spring never pass here. Goes directly to the catch statement.

            Void transaction = factory.withTransaction(
                    (session, tx) -> session.persist(user)
            ).await().indefinitely();


            factory.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.error("ERROR: ", exception);
        }

    }
// Other methods here down
}
```

Console

```
org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.reactive.vertx.VertxInstance]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.getService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.impl.MutinySessionFactoryImpl.<init>(MutinySessionFactoryImpl.java:48) ~[hibernate-reactive-core-1.0.0.CR3.jar:1.0.0.CR3]
    at org.hibernate.reactive.session.impl.ReactiveSessionFactoryImpl.unwrap(ReactiveSessionFactoryImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-reactive-core-1.0.0.CR3.jar:1.0.0.CR3]
    at cl.aurus.olimporeactivev3.client.infraestructure.repository.UserRepository.save(UserRepository.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at cl.aurus.olimporeactivev3.client.infraestructure.service.UserService.save(UserService.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at cl.aurus.olimporeactivev3.client.application.UserAuthRestController.authenticate(UserAuthRestController.java:92) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:336) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:259) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:469) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:261) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.request(FluxReceive.java:130) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.request(FluxPeek.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCollect.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeek.java:170) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:168) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.lambda$subscribe$2(FluxReceive.java:147) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.63.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Persistance.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="***">
        <provider>org.hibernate.reactive.provider.ReactivePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <!--DB conection-->
        <properties>

            <!-- PostgreSQL -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://***:***/***"/>

            <!-- Credentials -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="****"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*****"/>

            <!-- The Vert.x SQL Client connection pool size -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="100"/>

            <!-- Automatic schema export -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="none"/>

            <!--If load data needed-->
            <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="data.sql" />

            <!-- SQL statement logging -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.highlight_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: We would need to see what `CustomEntityManagerFactory` does.

Answer (score 0):

try to create your SessionFactory like this:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("***");
Mutiny.SessionFactory factory = emf.unwrap(Mutiny.SessionFactory.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a working example to demo Hibernate Reactive/Spring/Vertx, check [the complete source codes](https://github.com/hantsy/vertx-sandbox/tree/master/mutiny-spring-hibernate) here.

Just declare a `Mutiny.SessionFactory` bean, and then inject it as a normal Spring bean in your repository classes.

```java
    @Bean
    public Mutiny.SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("blogPU")
            .unwrap(Mutiny.SessionFactory.class);
    }
```